# gtm.js not firing for page view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

I'm using create-react-app and want to track the page view for each page. I
already created the custom page view tracker, and when I do the preview, the _event gtm.js is not firing.

I already looked at a similar problem but some say to add the gtm script after the **opening** body tag, I'm already doing that.

```html
   <head>
   <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-id');
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=..."
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

[image: current preview]

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. The fix for me was realising that I'm using a SPA (create-react-app does the same), which doesn't change the page it changes the history stack.

Updating the trigger to be a History change rather than a Page View fixed my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**The `<noscript>` tag is not Google Tag Manager**: it's just a pixel tracker Google uses to collect statistics about people blocking JavaScript.

**For GTM to work you need to insert the `<script>` tag** (the actual GTM snippet, or load it via custom code such as https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm). Once the snippet runs, it will create the `window.dataLayer` array and push the `gtm.js` event to it upon loading:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<noscript>` is for the users who have disabled Javascript in their browsers.
Instead you should insert the tracking code snippet provided by Google Analytics/Tag manager when you are setting up the container as the first item into the `<HEAD>`. it is something like follows,

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

to get yours, in Google Analytics, go to the admin section. in there under the property column select the property you want to redirect your data and select tracking info->tracking code.

In Google Tag Manager, once you go inside the container, click on the container code and you'll be able to find the tracking code there.

GA : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/#install_the_global_site_tag

GTM : https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart